# Removing the period from a price

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel to do my coding. Now I've save my price as this `123.45` and when I echo it out I get the same thing, which is correct and I want it to be saved like that in my database. The problem I have is that in order for me to be able to make a person pay a specific amount I need to remove the period so that it will look like this `12345`.

I don't know if I'm not searching properly but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: Just multiply it by 100

Comment: `str_replace('.', '', $price);` will strip the period character from `$price`.

Comment: @frozenjakalope I dunno, that seems like an overkill when you could just do what aynber suggested. **Edit:** I guess it'd be good in those instances where a price doesn't have a period within it.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: If the price is 123.45, why would you want to display it as 12345 since they don't have the same monetary? Are they the same values? I think your question has missing information.

Comment: @LeoRams - the prices would be different

Comment: @LeoRams Some payment APIs, such as Stripe, requires money amounts to be sent as cents instead of dollar.cents. I figured the question had something to do with that.

Comment: @aynber then your solution would work best then in that case since a dollar = 100 cents

Comment: @aynber - yep I have to do my money like that and thank you what you gave was what I was looking for

Comment: @Script47 That was what I was thinking, yeah. I've just a quick performance test for completeness and for both string and float values of `$price` multiplication is ~35 times faster over 10,000 runs (0.0042 vs 0.00011) microseconds.

Comment: But multiplication only works if the number is a float. Else `1` will become `100`. (Unless that is what is wanted)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if your concern is just to remove a period from a decimal number you can try PHP's function [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$x = 245.25;
$x = str_replace('.', '', $x);
echo $x;

// output
24525
```

This will provide all the numbers removing the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php `round()` function :

`echo round(123.45, 0);      // 123`

`echo round(123.55, 0);      // 124`

if not what you want you can use `@Shiv` solution

Answer (score 0):

@Nikki

if you want to store the amount in cent then multiply the amount by 100

```
$price = 123.45 * 100;

// output
12345
```

OR if you just want to remove the `.`, try like this

```
$price = 123.45;
$price = str_replace('.', '', $price);
echo $price;

// output
12345
```